# Android Play Store - App not installed, why this message appears?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, google-play

I have an issue when I try to open my app released on the Play Store. I already saw multiple answer to a similar question, but I tried them and it still doesn't change anything...

I developed an app in React Native, tried it multiple times with an USB connection between my Fairphone and my computer, and then I created a release on the Play Console, to have my app on the Play Store.

The issue occurred when I download the app from the Play Store : I can't open it, a toast message appears to say "App not installed". But weirdly some phones (Samsung for example) can ! I don't understand the issue so I don't know how to correct it...

[EDIT] If I go in the settings of my phone, select the app, and then open it from there it works [EDIT]

I read that it could be because of deeplinks, so I remove every "Linking" component that I had. I don't know if it can be a signature issue : I signed my .aab (not .apk) using jarsigner with a timestamp.

I am quiet in the dark here ... Does anyone know what could be the problem ?

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml if it can be useful to someone :

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"package="com.xxxxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Required -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <!-- Include this only if you are planning to use the camera roll -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" /> -->

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                  android:host="xxxx.com" />
        </intent-filter> -->
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: If you have the version installed by USB, then uninstall it, and only then install form Google Play as certificates don't match

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't change the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue, pretty simple. In the AndroidManifest.xml you need to be sure that "exported" is true :

```
android:exported="true"
```